# Append keys and values to one JSON object from multiple JSON files

Tags: javascript, python, json

I'm currently working with three json files.

master.json

```
 {
  "master":[
    {
      "sport": "soccer",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "sport": "football",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

data1.json

```
{
  "soccer": {
    "players": 11
  },
  "football": {
    "players": 12
  }
}
```

data2.json

```
{
  "soccer": {
    "stadiums": {
      "away": "StadiumA",
      "home": "StadiumB"
    }
  },
  "football": {
    "stadiums": {
      "away": "StadiumA",
      "home": "StadiumB"
    }
  }
}
```

What I'd like to do is combine attributes from each sport in each json file into the `master.json`.

This is what I'm looking for:

```
{
  "master":[
    {
      "sport": "soccer",
      "id": 1,
      "players": 11,
      "stadiums": {
        "away": "StadiumA",
        "home": "StadiumB"
      }

    },
    {
      "sport": "football",
      "id": 2,
      "players": 12,
      "stadiums": {
        "away": "StadiumA",
        "home": "StadiumB"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to include a conditional where the sport value in `data1` and `data2` must match what is in `master.json` to do the appending. So, if "baseball" is in `data1` and `data2` but not `master`, then it is not included.

I've tried using `underscore` in JavaScript and `json` in Python but to no luck. I can't seem to find a way to loop through all three json files to have them talking to each other, especially to see if the sport matches.

Any help would be appreciate. I'll also do my best to clarify and confusion.

Comment: I've tried requiring the json files in node and looping through them in Underscore. I've also tried messing with them in Python. I've had no issues working with one array of objects, but I'm stuck with how to handle three.

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your latest attempt.

Comment: Why, oh why, would you make a json that is a single object with an array that contains singleton objects? Why not something like `{'soccer':{'id':1},'football':{'id':2}}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to demonstrate the relative finesse of Python, I'll throw in a solution:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('master.json') as m, open('data1.json') as d1, open('data2.json') as d2:
    master = json.load(m, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    data1 = json.load(d1, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    data2 = json.load(d2, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

for i, obj in enumerate(master['master']):
    d1, d2 = data1.get(obj['sport']), data2.get(obj['sport'])
    if d1:
        master['master'][i].update(d1)
    if d2:
        master['master'][i].update(d2)

print(json.dumps(master,indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "master": [
    {
      "sport": "soccer",
      "id": 1,
      "players": 11,
      "stadiums": {
        "away": "StadiumA",
        "home": "StadiumB"
      }
    },
    {
      "sport": "football",
      "id": 2,
      "players": 12,
      "stadiums": {
        "away": "StadiumA",
        "home": "StadiumB"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the answer, I just realized you shouldn't need  to copy the `dicts` before you use them to update master. I was just being overly careful.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it. Bare in mind, this is for your case.

```
var master = {
  "master":[
    {
      "sport": "soccer",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "sport": "football",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}

var data1 = {
  "soccer": {
    "players": 11
  },
  "football": {
    "players": 12
  }
}

var data2 = {
  "soccer": {
    "stadiums": {
      "away": "StadiumA",
      "home": "StadiumB"
    }
  },
  "football": {
    "stadiums": {
      "away": "StadiumA",
      "home": "StadiumB"
    }
  }
}

var masterSports = master.master.map(function(object){
    return object.sport;
});

var data1Keep = {};
var data2Keep = {};

Object.keys(data1).map(function(key){
    if(masterSports.indexOf(key) > -1 && !data1Keep.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        data1Keep[key] = data1[key];
    }
});
Object.keys(data2).map(function(key){
    if(masterSports.indexOf(key) > -1 && !data2Keep.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        data2Keep[key] = data2[key];
    }
});

master.master.map(function(object){
    for(key in data1Keep){
        if(key == object.sport){
            for(i in data1Keep[key]){
                object[i] = data1Keep[key][i];
            }
        }
    }

    for(key2 in data2Keep){
        if(key2 == object.sport){
            for(j in data2Keep[key2]){
                object[j] = data2Keep[key2][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return object;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I went with the python solution, but I appreciate your JS contribution.

Comment: It looks a lot easier and better, so I don't blame you.